# What is the difference between colnames(x[1])<-"name" and colnames(x)[1]<-"name"?

Tags: r

I want to rename column names in `data.frame`,

```
> x=data.frame(name=c("n1","n2"),sex=c("F","M"))
> colnames(x[1])="Name"
> x
  name sex
1   n1   F
2   n2   M
> colnames(x)[1]="Name"
> x
  Name sex
1   n1   F
2   n2   M
>
```

Why does `colnames(x[1]) = "Name"` not work, while `colnames(x)[1]="Name"` does?

What is the reason? What is the difference betweent them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The too much information answer:
If you look at what each of the options "de-sugars" to:

```
# 1.
`[<-`(x, 1, value=`colnames<-`(x[1], 'Name'))
# 2.
`colnames<-`(x, `[<-`(colnames(x), 1, 'Name'))
```

The first option makes a new data.frame from just the first column, renames that column (successfully), and then tries to assign that data.frame back over the first column. `[<-.data.frame` will propagate the values, however will not rename existing columns based on the names of `value`.

The second option gets the colnames of the data.frame, updates the first value, and creates a new data.frame with the updated names.

---

(Answer to @Peng Peng's question here because I can't figure out how to get backtick quoting to work in a comment...)

The backtick is to quote the variable name. Consider the difference here:

```
x<-1
`x<-`<-1
```

The first assigns 1 to a variable called x, but the second assigns to a variable called `x<-`. These unusal variable names are actually used by the `<-` primitive function - you are allowed arbitrary function calls on the lhs of an assignment, and a function with `<-` appended to the name specifies how to perform the update (similar to `setf` in lisp).

Comment: what is the meaning of \``colnames<-\`` ? what does the character ` express?

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to modify the column names attribute of `x`, a data.frame.  Hence

```
colnames(x) <- ....
```

is correct, whether or not you assign one or more at the same time.

Comment: @Peng Peng in case this isn't clear, `x[1]` is a data frame, but it's a brand new data frame that just happens to be the first column of `x`. Changing the column name of the new data frame doesn't go back and change the column names in `x`.

Comment: Thank you, @shujua. Highlighting the fact that the result of x[1[ ss a different data frame from x is helpful.